# How to set different overflow on the html on different routes?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I need different overflows on different routes with styled components in my react app. some pages I don't want the page to be scrollable and others I need it to be. so I'm using this

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    html {
        overflow: ${({ location }) => (location.includes('visited') ? 'hidden' : 'auto')};
    }
`
```

oh and I'm using it like so:

```
    return (
        <Router>
            <GlobalStyle location={window.location.pathname} />
```

but it's not working. this is my index.html

```
  <style>
      html { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
      body { height: 100%; }
  </style>
```

how can I force my app to render different styles when I need it too?

also can confirm `location.includes` is definitely working. I even set: `? 'hidden' : 'auto')};` to be `? 'hidden' : 'hidden')}` and it came through as `auto`

Comment: why's this been downvoted???

Comment: I'm curious about : `location.includes('visited')` how is that supposed to work ?

Comment: hey @G-Cyrillus. im doing this `location={window.location.pathname}` so the value of window.location.pathname is say '/home'. and then when I pass that in here: `overflow: ${({ location }) => (location` is the equivalent of saying `/home`.includes('visited') which would return false in this case

Comment: for the downvote, it might be because of clarity, not enough code to demonstrate the issue or an obvious duplicate

Comment: okay , i get it, but it will never be visited then ? maybe /visited ?

Comment: well it's quite clear what I'm asking? and if not, say what isn't clear. and if there's a duplicate, then tell me. some people on this site man

Comment: No idea why one downvoted . I often think a downvote requires a reason told  to be valuable to mind about ;)

Comment: haha yeh. but some of us need the rep :'(

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on `GlobalStyle` location. If you want to have it in the top level component you can use `useLocation` hook. Alternatively wrap all pages in a `Layout` component which would render `children` and `GlobalStyle`.

**Examples**

```js
const { Fragment, useState, useEffect } = React;
const { createGlobalStyle } = styled;
const { Switch, Link, Route, HashRouter, useLocation, useHistory } = ReactRouterDOM;

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    overflow: ${({location: {pathname} = {}} = {}) => ['/no-overflow','/'].includes(pathname) ? 'hidden' : 'scroll'};
  }
`

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  height: 200vh;
`

const Layout = (props) => {
  return <Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle {...props}/>
      {props.children}
    </Fragment>
}

const MustNotHaveOverflow = (props) => {

  return <Layout {...props}>
    <StyledDiv>No overflow</StyledDiv>
  </Layout>
}

const MustHaveOverflow = (props) => {

  return <Layout {...props}>
    <StyledDiv>Overflow</StyledDiv>
  </Layout>
}

const App = () => {
  
  const location = useLocation()

return <div>
  <GlobalStyle location={location}/>
  <div>
    <Link to="/no-overflow">No Overflow</Link>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Link to="/overflow">Overflow</Link>
  </div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/no-overflow" component={MustNotHaveOverflow}/>
    <Route path="/overflow" component={MustHaveOverflow}/>
    <Route component={MustNotHaveOverflow}/>
  </Switch>
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/react-router@3.0.2/umd/react-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.2.0/umd/react-router-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/styled-components@4.0.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```